# OpenCL Platform Issues

Tags: fedora, amd, fglrx

My current setup at the moment is I have an Nvidia card and an AMD (OpenCl 2.0 compatible) APU.

I'm running Fedora 20.

The aim is to test speed differences between APU vs [CPU+Graphics]. By querying the platforms available I get:

```
  1.1 Name       : AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  1.2 Vendor     : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  1.3 Version    : OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1445.5)
  1.4 Profile    : FULL_PROFILE

  2.1 Name       : NVIDIA CUDA
  2.2 Vendor     : NVIDIA Corporation
  2.3 Version    : OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.5.19
  2.4 Profile    : FULL_PROFILE
```

The NVidia card only having OpenCL v1.1 I'm not surprised about, but the AMD APU really should be OpenCL v2.0 compatible.

I've installed the AMD App SDK on a previous kernel (not the current), but I don't understand why the information hasn't changed on the current kernel.  Can anyone help me make sure I'm getting the correct information

**Edit#1 - `lshw -numeric -c display` output as requested**

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics] [1002:130F]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:d2000000-d27fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe200000-fe23ffff memory:fe240000-fe25ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 980] [10DE:13C0]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fe000000-fe07ffff
```

Comment: Your question as written, "What's your Unix or Linux question? Be specific" contains good advice. :-)

Comment: Can you please post the output of `lshw -numeric -C display`.

Comment: @JasonAzze - Odd, I did not name it that. Originally I called it 'OpenCL Platform issues' but I walked away from my the machine for an hour and came back to it and posted without thinking...

Comment: @eyoung100 - I'm at home now, so I can't give you the precise output but I can tell you that it is a Maxwell card currently running the `nouveau` driver.

Comment: That doesn't help I need the models not the manufacturers

Comment: @eyoung100 - added the output

Comment: Now if you Google Radeon Kaveri r7 OpenCL or Kaveri Radeon r7 OpenCL you'll see that everyone elses OpenCL report also contains 1.2, so I would say that the 2,0 support will come shortly.

Comment: @eyoung100 - true, but what then to make of [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx), where the current AMD Catalyst suite contains the OpenCL 2.0 driver?

Comment: Look at the chart labeled "AMD APU Product Family Compatibility".  In the List is the ​​AMD A10-7850K (your card).  If the output above states  OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1445.5), it will stay at  OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP, and OpenCL2.0 is backwards compatible with 1.2.  The only way you can make that OpenCL2 is with a firmware upgrade, if that's even possible, as there may not be newer firmware available

Comment: @eyoung100 - Hmm. I'm now confused with how OpenCL works. I was under the impression that OpenCL 2.0 sources were already compiled onto the card, and that in order to access them all I need is the right driver (with the appropriate headers) in my installation. But from what I now gather from what you're possibly hinting, you're saying that I need to compile the OpenCL 2.0 sources myself and flash the card with it. But so far as I've seen, OpenCL contains only [headers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).... so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  You can use the 2.0 SDK to develop against 2.0.  If everything works right, whatever you build will be backwards compatible.  In order to do anything you need a [GPU BIOS Flash](http://www.overclock.net/t/1353325/tutorial-atiwinflash-how-to-flash-the-bios-of-your-ati-cards) that is officially supported by AMD.  I don't recommend this as I will not be held responsible if your card becomes a Brick

Comment: Still confused - Are you saying that my card already has OpenCLv2.0 on it and that I simply need to wait for the right drivers to be released, or are you saying that my card is OpenCLv2.0 capable but I will still need to flash it (with some image) in order to actually use it as such